# calculate the ratio of days left to days in month

Tags: reporting, formula

When creating a formula in a report, I need the syntax to calculate the fraction or percent of days past in the month versus days left in the month, e.g., if month ids 30 days and there are currently 10 days past then then fraction should be .33 or 33%.

Comment: Bartley -- have you tried anything yet?

Comment: not a sausage!!

Comment: I've given your question some thought and it's a difficult one without having more context as to what type of report you want to create (Fields Types and Ranges). I think you're going to need to find a way of "normalizing" the daily data your reporting on, perhaps with Record Counts or Summary Totals, in order to break that down so you can use AMOUNT:SUM in conjunction with PREVGROUPVAL and PARENTGROUPVAL summary formula functions to get the percentages you're looking for.